# Automatically add extra products for free

Tags: cart, products

In current webshop (Opencart) we have built a custom feature in the system cart-handler that automatically add x products for every 10 y ordered. It looks like buy 20 and get 2 extra for free.

If we were to add the same to Magento. Where should we look. Which file needs to be modified?

Comment: You can Create a Shopping Cart Price Rule by using admin. You can refer below link.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-setup-buy-x-get-y-free

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can only change prices of products already in the cart, but not actively adding those products to the cart if you reach your "buy 10 products of type X" quantity.  You have to have it in the cart already and only get a discount for them. if you do not have them in the cart: nothing will happen.
I know that there are some extensions that address this, but i do not know if there are any compliant to a free license.

The problem with "buy X get Y for free" alsow was, that it is not cross product. So you cannot "buy 10 of X and get i of Y free" but only "buy 10 of X and get Y of X for free".